# Data in Pandas becomes NaN when I add it to another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to pull Worldwide data from a data set and add the column to another dataframe using pandas, but the data becomes NaN everytime I run the code. The same code works for when I try to pull US data.

Code:

```
fb_us_data = us_data[us_data.app_id == fb_key]
fb_ww_data = ww_data[ww_data.app_id == fb_key]
fb_intl_data = fb_us_data[["app_id","date"]]
fb_intl_data['total_users_ww'] = fb_us_data['total_users']
fb_intl_data["total_users_us"] = fb_us_data['total_users']
print(fb_intl_data)`
```

Output:

```
                      app_id       date  total_users_ww  total_users_us
158515  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2015-09-28             NaN       114609170
158516  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2015-10-05             NaN       115642838
158517  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2015-10-12             NaN       116414827
158518  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2015-10-19             NaN       117005866
158519  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2015-10-26             NaN       118743332
...                          ...        ...             ...             ...
158885  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2022-10-31             NaN       228981651
158886  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2022-11-07             NaN       229721851
158887  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2022-11-14             NaN       228069299
158888  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2022-11-21             NaN       228729072
158889  55c530a702ac64f9c0002dff 2022-11-28             NaN       225447696

[375 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Please reproduce the problem on a smaller dataset and post the source code and the dataset.

Comment: I think you meant `fb_intl_data['total_users_ww'] = fb_ww_data['total_users']`. Would need a basic data set to see where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here come from indexes try reseting index before adding like this:

```
fb_us_data = us_data[us_data.app_id == fb_key].copy()
fb_ww_data = ww_data[ww_data.app_id == fb_key].copy()
fb_us_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
fb_ww_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```